# How to Choose Between Real-Time, Low-Latency and Normal Kernels on Startup?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, startup, real-time

For instance, I know it's possible to easily install several desktop interfaces and choose what session to log into on startup.

Is this type of thing possible for choosing between kernels? I would like to be able to install the low latency and realtime kernels on my system while still being able to use the normal kernel easily when doing everyday chores such as just checking my email and doing my school.

Basically, I would like to log into my system using a minimal window manager and a low-latency kernel only when I'm doing things such as music production.

System specs:

- Debian Bullseye, Stable
- amd64 (Intel i2)
- HP Compaq 8000 Elite Convertible Minitower
- 8GB RAM

Thank you in advance, and God bless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to choose your kernel at GRUB2 boot menu.
See under `Advanced options for Debian`. Some GRUB2 config:

- Disable hidden GRUB2 boot menu in `/etc/default/grub`. Comment `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="5"`
  and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"` or change it to false.
- Set a resonable time to see the menu `GRUB_TIMEOUT="3"`